# how convert manifest.xml to binary for apk with programming in android

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, apktool, android-signing

I want to replace the `AndroidManifest.xml` in an `APK` file.

How can I encode an `AndroidManifest.XML` ***without apktool*** with **programming in android** and replace it in `APK` file?

May someone give an example?

Comment: You can not just replace the `AndroidManifest.xml` file inside the `apk` because after doing this the checksum and the signature of the `apk` are not valid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Without using software such as APKtool to unpack and then re-sign a decompiled apk, it is not possible to change a signed app's manifest.

Comment: Is it not possible to convert just my AndroidManifest.xml with programming in android?

Comment: If you have access to the full source code, you can just _change_ the manifest and recompile. However, from your question it sounds like you are trying to change an already compiled app.

Answer (score -1):

You could decompile your apk with the APK-Tool. Then you could just edit your manifest and compile it (& create a new apk).
You will however still have to sign your App.

Here's the link for the [APK-Tool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)

Comment: without apktool. how with programming in android??

Comment: Your manifest is within your apk, which is signed, so changing it dynamically would invalidate the whole package. My guess is dynamically changing the manifest is not possible.